# References for basics of Piecewise-Deterministic Markov Processes

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I am looking for introductory/pedagogical material to Piecewise-Deterministic Markov Processes (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise-deterministic_Markov_process) (For the moment I am interested in construction techniques, basic properties, motivation for considering them, simple examples, etc.).

The only source I have is the book "Markov models and Optimization" by Davis which seems quiet good (at a level which I can more or less understand), but maybe there are some more recent lecture notes/survey articles/(chapters of) books that you recommend as a starter to get into the topic.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Jacobsen, Martin. [Piecewise Deterministic Markov Processes](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/0-8176-4463-6_7) in *Point process theory and applications: marked point and piecewise deterministic processes* Birkhäuser Boston, 2006 (ISBN 978-0-8176-4215-0)